# RSelenium - selecting parent element with xpath

Tags: r, xpath, rselenium

I'm trying to capture a csv available on a webpage via a button using RSelenium.  The relevant html is:

```
<a ng-click='download()'><i class='csv-download'></i> Download</a>
```

I can select the `i` element via it's class with:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".csv-download")
```

I think to automate a button push I need to select the parent `a` element, but can't figure out how to do this.  `xpath` seems the best way:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//i[@class='csv-download']/parent::*")
Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException
```

Must be something wrong with the xpath formula.  Grateful for assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stay with CSS selectors and rely on the `ng-click` attribute:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', "a[ng-click*=download]")
```

where `*=` means "contains".

---

But, to answer what you were asking about, use `..`:

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', "//i[@class='csv-download']/..")
```